# cannot connect labtop to windows server 2008 domain?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008

This is my first time with Windows server.  I installed Windows Server 2008 on VMWare,
installed an active directory domain, and created a computer and a user.

I tried to connect using the Windows XP of the same computer that VMWARE is installed on and it contacted the server with no problem.

When I tried to connect from my laptop, it shows the following message:

```
a domain controller for the domain MYSERVER0 could not be contacted.
```

Comment: okay so what's your dns set to? And what do you mean by connect? Like join the pc to the domain? You need alot more info here... Start with your DNS and DHCP settings. And of course guest to guest is going to work on a ESX host (just guessing ESX here...) as VMware is handling the NAT.

Comment: From the laptop can you ping the ip of the Domain Controller (that's the VM you have set up right?).  I am betting you cannot.  You probably need to ensure that you hosts virtual networking is properly set up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**solution:**
the default network adapter setting is **NAT** when i should have changed it to **Bridged**.
**why**? Here is the answer From the VMWARE manual:

**Bridged networking:** connects a virtual machine to a network by using the host
computer’s network adapter. If your host computer is on a network, this is often the
easiest way to give your virtual machine access to that network. The virtual network
adapter in the virtual machine connects to the physical network adapter in your host
computer, allowing it to connect to the LAN the host computer uses.
Bridged networking configures your virtual machine as a unique identity on the
network, separate from and unrelated to its host. It makes the virtual machine visible
to other computers on the network, and they can communicate directly with the virtual
machine. Bridged networking works with both wired and wireless physical host
network cards.

**NAT:** configures a virtual machine to share the IP and MAC addresses of the host.
The virtual machine and the host share a single network identity that is not visible
outside the network.